# Which function to override if a reference to the object is incremented/decremented

Tags: python, refcounting

I have a pretty basic doubt in Python. Is there a function that is called when the ref count of an object is being increased?

I am sure there should be a double underscore method that I can override in my class.
Basically I am looking for a **ref** method in Foo class.

```
class Foo():
    def __ref__(self):
        print ("refcount increased by 1")

ref1 = Foo()
ref2 = ref1 # prints "refcount increased by 1"
ref3 = ref2 # prints "refcount increased by 1"
```

PS: I am aware of `sys.getrefcount`

Comment: "Is there a function that is called when the ref count of an object is being increased?...I am sure there should be a double underscore method that I can override in my class." Why would you think that? Those are internal details of the CPython runtime, and they are not exposed. Why do you need this?

Comment: Reference counting is an implementation detail of CPython. There is no special method relating to it.

Comment: Note, the only thing close to this is `__del__` which is called when a reference count reaches zero, but even that is a CPython implementation detail, the spec just says it is called "when an instance is about to be destroyed"

Comment: Can you clarify what behaviour you expect, or what you are trying to achieve? The "method" as shown would be infinitely recursing, since ``self`` inherently is a reference to the object.

Comment: In case removing the ``super().__ref__(self)`` line was in response to my comment – that is not what was meant. In a method, the name ``self`` is a regular variable *which increases the reference count*. Just passing the instance *into* ``__ref__`` as ``self`` would increase the reference count, thereby requiring to call ``self.__ref__()``, thereby passing the instance *into* ``__ref__`` as ``self``, which would increase the reference count, thereby requiring to call ``self.__ref__()``, thereby passing the instance *into* ``__ref__`` as ``self``, which would …

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No I didnt. I thought other readers might get confused and doesn't add anything to the question

Answer (score 1):

There's no such hook. It'd break all kinds of stuff, including C-level code that relies on the ability to incref objects without triggering interpreted code. It'd be incompatible with non-refcounted Python implementations (which is most of them). It'd be incompatible with any hypothetical future non-refcounted CPython implementations (unlikely as such would be). It'd be incompatible with *itself*, because the mere act of calling or leaving such a method would alter the object's refcount, requiring it to trigger again infinitely, and doing anything with the object inside the method would also modify the refcount and cause another trigger even if you could reach the method body.

Answer (score 1):

[There is no special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) invoked by the VM for reference counting. Reference counting is an implementation detail of the CPython VM and not visible outside of implementation-specific helpers.

> #### [reference count](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-reference-count) (Python glossary)
>
> The number of references to an object. When the reference count of an
> object drops to zero, it is deallocated. *Reference counting is
> generally not visible to Python code*, but it is a key element of the
> CPython implementation. The `sys` module defines a `getrefcount()`
> function that programmers can call to return the reference count for a
> particular object.

---

CPython internally uses [C macros/functions to manage reference counts](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html#reference-counting). For CPython 3.8, the [reference count is a C integer](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0a5b30d98913e84f80ecea2b861e96d8f67c89e9/Include/object.h#L106) and [omitting debug actions reference counting is defined as](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0a5b30d98913e84f80ecea2b861e96d8f67c89e9/Include/object.h#L456-L482):

```
static inline void _Py_INCREF(PyObject *op)
{
    op->ob_refcnt++;
}
```

Getting a reference merely increases the reference count. This is purely a C increment operation, and *no Python code can be invoked when increasing the reference count*.

```
// omitting lineno/filename used for debug
static inline void _Py_DECREF(PyObject *op)
{
    _Py_DEC_REFTOTAL;
    if (--op->ob_refcnt != 0) {
    }
    else {
        _Py_Dealloc(op);
    }
}
```

Releasing a reference decrements the reference count, and immediately triggers de-allocation for unreferenced objects. Decrementing is purely a C decrement operation, and *no Python code can be invoked when decreasing the reference count*. Only after decrementing the reference count to 0 can `_Py_Dealloc` eventually invoke Python code via `__del__`.